# intelligent split string in excel formula - full words

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to split string that the words isn't split and result string is max 30 chars ?

```
input cell = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt'

output cell = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
```

I need only formula, not VBA.

Comment: Find the locations or the spaces, pick the one closest to but below 30, take the substring up to that location, remove any period or comma.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Non-[let function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) version:

[image]

```
=IF(RIGHT(IF(RIGHT(LEFT(A2,31),1)=" ",LEFT(A2,30),LEFT(A2,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,30)," ","@",(LEN(LEFT(A2,30))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,30)," ","")))))-1)),1)=",",
LEFT(IF(RIGHT(LEFT(A2,31),1)=" ",LEFT(A2,30),LEFT(A2,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,30)," ","@",(LEN(LEFT(A2,30))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,30)," ","")))))-1)),LEN(IF(RIGHT(LEFT(A2,31),1)=" ",LEFT(A2,30),LEFT(A2,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,30)," ","@",(LEN(LEFT(A2,30))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,30)," ","")))))-1)))-1),
IF(RIGHT(LEFT(A2,31),1)=" ",LEFT(A2,30),LEFT(A2,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,30)," ","@",(LEN(LEFT(A2,30))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,30)," ","")))))-1)))
```

Office 365 `Let` [function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) version:

```
=LET(a,IF(RIGHT(LEFT(A2,31),1)=" ",LEFT(A2,30),LEFT(A2,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,30)," ","@",(LEN(LEFT(A2,30))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,30)," ","")))))-1)),IF(RIGHT(a,1)=",",LEFT(a,LEN(a)-1),a))
```

Comment: thnx, awesome ! it's extremely complicated but it works.

Comment: If it works, remember to mark the answer, so others may find it too

Comment: Also, check my let function version

Answer (score 1):

Simpler array formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(LEFT(A1,MAX(IF(MID(A1,ROW($1:$30),1)=" ",ROW($1:$30))))),",","")
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`FILTERXML()` may give you best desired result with more option. Try below formula-

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[string-length(.) <=30]")
```

[image]